# Moving an old Rose bush

Tags: transplanting, roses

We uncovered this old neglected Rose bush after starting to clear the back garden which had been overgrown in field bindweed, and wandering Jew.  It has a diameter of 10 cm so a bit larger then the other Rose bush I have.

[image: Rose bush]

I'm going to build a shed at this site. Can I move the Rose at all to another site in the garden? The shed will be 1 m off the ground so I could leave it there but it would be largely shaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the top has already been severely pruned, so the inevitable root damage should be balanced out - go ahead and move it, I say. If you know someone with an excavator, it might be the easier way to go about that...

Comment: Excavator? How big would the root ball be that we would need an excavator?   There is no access anyway for any heavy machinery.  All the site clearance is being done by hand, and chain saws.

Comment: Need, no, and if you can't get one in there, that's just as well. Far easier than digging it out by hand, if it is an option. A 4"/10 cm rose trunk is likely to have a substantial rootball, but you'll know shortly, I guess.